# Including a class file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a [class from github](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query/blob/master/MinecraftQuery.class.php) I need to include in my project and in my HomeController. I moved it inside of /app/libs and added it to the composer file...

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
        "app/libs",
        ...
    ]
},
```

I assumed that the folder would autoload all of the files, so I tried to do this in my HomeController...

```
$Query = new MinecraftQuery();
```

But I get the error

```
syntax error, unexpected '$Query' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run following command from your `terminal/command prompt` of your project's root folder:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

You need to use the `composer dump-autoload` command to rebuild the class map every time you add a new file in your project within `classmap` of `autoload` section in `composer.json` file. Read [this article](http://daylerees.com/composer-primer) to learn more about `composer`.

**Update:** For the `syntax error` try to find the line number where the error is being happened for wrong syntax and fix it, it seems that `$Query` is causing the problem, where is this code `$Query = new MinecraftQuery();` located ? Post more code.

Probably you put this line `$Query = new MinecraftQuery();` inside a class but out side any method or not in any class or function.

**Solution:** The line `$Query = new MinecraftQuery();` was outside any method of a class.

Comment: Hi, I did that and the error still appears. Also you answered my third question in a row. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: It's $Query = new MinecraftQuery();

Comment: Where have you put this line ?

Comment: Very top, below   protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

Comment: Put it inside a `function/method`.